# Freeswitch wrong caller id number after bridge

Tags: sip, voip, telephony, freeswitch

I have a configured gateway and one dialplan for bridging an inbound call through the gateway to another number. This part works.

Now I want that the number of the inbound call is displayed in the phone after the bridge. This part doesn't work. I've tried many combinations, but every time the number from the provider is shown up.

**/etc/freeswitch/sip_profiles/external/MyGateway.xml**

```
<gateway name="MyGateway">
  <param name="username" value="SIP_USERNAME"/>
  <param name="password" value="SIP_PASSWORD"/>
  <param name="proxy" value="sip.provider.com"/>
  <param name="register" value="true"/>
</gateway>
```

**/etc/freeswitch/dialplan/public/MyExtension.xml**

```
<extension name="bridge">
  <condition field="destination_number" expression="^SIP_USERNAME$">

  <action application="set" data="bypass_media=true"/>
  <action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/MyProvider/+49123456789"/>

  </condition>
</extension>
```

**This is what i've tested in the dialplan before the line with "bypass_media=true"**

some of the commands changed the INVITE and/or RINGING request, but nothing changed the number on the phone after the bridge. I've also tried "export" instead of "set".

(I know that I can get the caller number with ${caller_id_number} - I just used 'ImCallingYou' for easy debugging)

```
<action application="set" data="initial_callee_id_name='ImCallingYou'"/>
<action application="set" data="initial_callee_id_number=999999999"/>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--> Remote-Party-ID: "ImCallingYou" <sip:999999999@GATEWAY_IP>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no
```

```
<action application="set" data="origination_caller_id_name='ImCallingYou'"/>
<action application="set" data="origination_caller_id_number=999999999"/>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--> nothing changed
```

```
<action application="set" data="sip_callee_id_name=ImCallingYou"/>
<action application="set" data="sip_callee_id_number=999999999" />
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--> Remote-Party-ID: "ImCallingYou" <sip:999999999@GATEWAY_IP>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no
```

```
<action application="set" data="effective_caller_id_name=ImCallingYou"/>
<action application="set" data="effective_caller_id_number=999999999"/>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--> From: "ImCallingYou" <sip:SIP_USERNAME@sip.provider.com>;tag=1010101010101
```

```
<action application="set" data="sip_from_display=ImCallingYou"/>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--> nothing changed
```

```
<action application="set" data="sip_cid_type=pid"/>
<action application="set" data="origination_caller_id_name=ImCallingYou"/>
<action application="set" data="origination_caller_id_number=999999999"/>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--> nothing changed
```

```
<action application="set" data="sip_cid_type=rpid"/>
<action application="set" data="origination_caller_id_name=ImCallingYou"/>
<action application="set" data="origination_caller_id_number=999999999"/>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--> nothing changed
```

```
<action application="bridge" data="{sip_cid_type=rpid,origination_caller_id_name=ImCallingYou,origination_caller_id_number=999999999}sofia/gateway/MyProvider/+49123456789"/>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--> From: "ImCallingYou" <sip:SIP_USERNAME@sip.provider.com>;tag=10101010101
--> Remote-Party-ID: "ImCallingYou" <sip:999999999@GATEWAY_IP>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this in Gateway config:

```
<param name="caller-id-in-from" value="true"/>
```

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Gateways+Configuration#GatewaysConfiguration-CallerID

Comment: Yes, i've tried this. The problem with this is, that I have to use the following for my gateway config, or my provider sends no response to my INVITE request:

<param name="caller-id-in-from" value="true"/>
<param name="from-domain" value="sip.provider.com"/>

and then i can only set "{sip_cid_type=rpid,origination_caller_id_name=test} in my bridge request. The id name "test" is then showing up in the From field and the Remote-Party-ID field, but in changes nothing at the endpoint...

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. You are saying that if you set "caller-id-in-from" in gateway profile, you are not getting response from your provider? Correct?

Comment: I do not understand, why caller-id-in-from can't be added to your provider profile? Are you sure that because of it you are not getting responses to your invite? What invite is being sent in this case? With proper from header?

Comment: I've tested it again... if I **don't** set the "caller-id-in-from", then I get an response to the invite request and this is what freeswitch sends ==> [From: "L1" <sip:SIP_USERNAME@sip.provider.com>;tag=101010101 && Remote-Party-ID: "L1" <sip:#1017244444444@sip.provider.com>;party=calling;screen=yes;privacy=off] and if I **set** the "caller-id-in-from", then i don't get an response and this is what freeswitch sends ==> [From: "L1" <sip:%231017244444444@FREESWITCH_IP>;tag=101010101 && Remote-Party-ID: "L1" <sip:#1017244444444@FREESWITCH_IP>;party=calling;screen=yes;privacy=off]

Comment: So my problem is, that i must use this combination in the "From"-field => sip:SIP_USERNAME@sip.provider.com ... and if I change this values, the call will not be established :-/

Comment: I can't be sure because I do not see logs and I do not know your configuration, but for me it seems that your Invite packet is formed in a way you provider do not like it, not because of "caller-id-in-from" and that why provider do not replies to it. So I would recommend to use "caller-id-in-from" and try to figure out what is wrong with your Invite. Maybe you are putting some garbage in From field like % sign. Just diff 2 invites and try to find out what is wrong. If you want to change from field, you must use "caller-id-in-from".